# Remote independent contractor needs short onsite training in US - what is the Visa requirement?

Tags: usa, visa, working-visas, business

As a small US based firm, we have offered a contract to a candidate as a remote independent contractor, who does not stay or work in the US. We would require the person to attend our in person 1 week training first, post which s/he can work with us from his/her country remotely. What visa would be required for the person to attend the training in person?

Is a B1 visa sufficient, if we do not pay the person for his/her attending the workshop but just reimburse the costs of his/her travel and stay? Or does this person count as an employee of our firm, and this must be a work visa?

Comment: This probably works better on [Travel.SE], since it's about a short trip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The USCIS website says that [acceptable activities on B-1 visa](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-visitors-business/b-1-temporary-business-visitor) include "Participating in short-term training" and "Consulting with business associates", among others.  What you described should be fine.

If, on the other hand, you wanted them to do some of the work while in the US, that's when it could be a problem.